# Arangodb AQL Query for multiple edge definitions

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am new to graph databases and arangodb too.
I try to query a graph with different edge definitions and didn't find any example for this. A query to get a result for one edge I found.

```
FOR p IN person
  FOR vx, ex, px IN ANY p GRAPH "test" FILTER vx.brand == "BMW" RETURN DISTINCT p
```

**For example:**
I have vertices "person", "car" and "house" and edges "has_car" (person->car) and "lives_in" (person->house). To try out I created three graphs. One for each edge definition and one with both edge definitions.

**My question**: What is the right way to query:

1. Persons who have a "BMW" and live in a "Castle"
2. Persons who live in a "Skyscraper" and don't have a car
3. Persons who live in a "Skyscraper" and don't have a "BMW"

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to store additional relations, possible paths with different lengths, and find all paths? Or will the model stay similar to this? It might be easier to use collection sets instead of a named graph and do multiple traversals with a depth of one in your case.

Answer (score 1):

What if you started from an end? That way you can check a [whole path](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#filtering-on-paths).

for an example following is starting from a BMW car (for the first question)

```
for car in Car filter car.brand=="BMW"
  for v,e,p in 0..2 any car._id graph 'test'
    filter p.edges[0]!=null && is_same_collection('has_car', p.edges[0])
    && p.vertices[1]!=null && is_same_collection('Person', p.vertices[1])
    && p.edges[1]!=null && is_same_collection('lives_in', p.edges[1])
    && p.vertices[2]!=null && p.vertices[2].house=="Castle"
  return distinct(p.vertices[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try if I have time for this again. Do you have examples for case 2 and 3, too?